# Python - Get empty key from yml file

Tags: python, yaml

I have a lot yaml file names that have similar structure but with different data. I need to parse out selective data, and put into a single csv (excel) file as three columns.

But i facing an issue with empty key, that always gives me an "KeyError: 'port'"

my yaml file example:

```
base:
   server: 10.100.80.47
   port: 3306
   namePrefix: well
   user: user1
   password: kjj&%$

 base:
   server: 10.100.80.48
   port: 
   namePrefix: done
   user: user2
   password: fhfh#$%
```

In the second block i have an empty "port", and my script is stuck on that point.
**I need that always that an empty key is found it doesn't write anything.**

```
   from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
   from queue import Empty
   import yaml
   import csv
   import glob


   yaml_file_names = glob.glob('./*.yaml')

   rows_to_write = []

   for i, each_yaml_file in enumerate(yaml_file_names):
   print("Processing file {} of {} file name: {}".format(
    i+1, len(yaml_file_names),each_yaml_file))

   with open(each_yaml_file) as file: 
    data = yaml.safe_load(file)


   for v in data:
    if "port" in v == "": 
    data['base']['port'] = ""  



  rows_to_write.append([data['base']['server'],data['base']['port'],data['server']['host'],data['server']['contex']])


  with open('output_csv_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    csv_writer.writerow(["server","port","hostname", "contextPath"])
    csv_writer.writerows(rows_to_write)
    print("Output file output_csv_file.csv created")
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: this is wrong `"port" in v == ""` - code `"port" in v` gives `True` or `False` so you compare `False == ""` or `True == ""` - and both gives `False` - so it never runs `data['base']['port'] = ""`

Comment: you should rather use `if ("port" not in v["base"]) or (v["base"]["port"] is None): v["base"]["port"] = ""`. And probably it may need `for key, val in data.items():` but I can't run it to check it.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you really have in `v` - ie. `print( v )`, `print( "port" in v )`, `print( "port" in v == "" )`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the key by index e.g.

```
data['base']['port']
```

But what you want is to access it with the get method like so:

```
data['base'].get('port')
```

This way if the key does not exists it return None as default, and you could even change the default value to whatever you want by passing it as the second parameter.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i still have the same error

Comment: @Paulo maybe you still get error because you have problem in different place - but you didn't show full error message and we don't know what is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

In PyYAML, an empty element is returned as `None`, not an empty string.

```py
if data['base']['port'] is None: 
    data['base']['port'] = ""
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i still have the same error

Comment: @Paulo maybe you still get error because you have problem in different place - but you didn't show full error message and we don't know what is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your yaml file is invalid. In yaml file, whenever you have a key (like `port:` in your example) you **must** provide a value, you cannot leave it empty and go to the next line. Unless the value is the next bunch of keys of course, but in that case you need to ident the following lines one step more, which is obviously not what you intend to do here.

This is likely why you cannot parse the file as expected with the python yaml module. If you are the creator of those yaml file, you really need to put a key in the file like `port: None` if you don't want to provide a value for the port, or even better you just not provide any port key at all.
If they are provided to you by someone else, ask them to provide valid yaml files.

Then the other solutions posted should work.